# IdentityServer4 UserInfo Endpoint Implementation?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

How is the UserInfo endpoint is implemented in `IdentityServer4`?

I'm asking because I'm thinking of having a cache saving those details for me to prevent from querying the DB everytime I need Info about the users.

If there's some sort of a dictionary behind the endpoint that saves the claims of the authenticated users and refresh them once in a while that's great.

 But if it accesses the users store every time it might be better having a cache processing the request and after the request is authorized fetches the data quickly.

Answer (score 0):

How is it implemented?
The source code is here ... https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4